# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Videos$List

Tags: android, youtube-api, retrofit2, rx-android

**LogCat :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Videos$List
```

**Exception :** The `onError` is called in the code bellow

```
    IService mService = application.getIService(Constants.mYoutubeUrl);
subscription = mService.getYoutubeVideos(Constants.mYoutubeKey ,Constants.mYoutubeChannelId )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
                .subscribe(new Observer<YouTube.Videos.List>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        videoMvpView.showMessage(R.string.probleme_connection);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(YouTube.Videos.List videos) {
                        videoMvpView.showVideos(videos);
                        videoMvpView.showSelectedVideo(((Video)videos.get(0)).getSnippet().getTitle());
                    }
                });
```

**IService.java**

```
public interface IService {
@GET("/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20")
Observable<YouTube.Videos.List> getYoutubeVideos(@Query("key") String key, @Query("channelId") String channelId);


class Factory {
    public static IService create(String baseUrl) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(IService.class);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory that you use **YouTube.Videos.List** class, if not the take the raw string response convert it to pojo using [json2schema](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) then try using it, that might help and if you have to use than you need to check the structure of **YouTube.Videos.List** class, if you can provide the raw response it might help to solve the issue